# Reverse and modify copy file to all subfolders command, xargs

Tags: find, cp, xargs

i found this online it copy file to every sub folder on the current dir for full tree depth

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 cp -v  .htaccess
```

now would be nice if it could ask if the file already exist or at least overwrite if file already exists.

Is there way to reverse this command so it can actually remove matching file from every subfolder?

Comment: For confirmation of overwrite, add `-i` to the `cp` flags.

Answer (score 1):

[Find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) is extremely versatile, the -delete and -name *pattern*  options may helpful for what you want.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.htaccess' -delete
```